# Map two checkboxes to a picklist?

Tags: picklist, map, translation, checkbox

Anyway I could transfer two existing checkboxes to a picklist? There's a few thousand entries that would need to do it manually. As far as I could see I can't edit two seperate checkboxes to one picklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a non-dev solution you could create the picklist field, export the record IDs and checkbox values, and then use Excel to decide the logic of which combinations map to which value in the new picklist column... Then export values to CSV and do a record update in Data Loader.

As a dev solution you could create the picklist field and then run some one-shot Apex code in Dev Console that retrieves the result set, iterates through, reads the checkboxes, sets a picklist value based on them, and then updates all the records.